# Page / Control Event Bubbling Direction in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Doing some preliminary testing in ASP.NET(I couldnt find any answers from searching), it seems that page/control events change their bubble / trickle direction depending on what the event is.

For example, the `OnLoad` event for Pages and Controls always starts at the 'eldest' parent, and trickles firing this event down the object hierarchy to the 'youngest' object, whereas the `OnInit` event works in reverse, and starts at the 'youngest' object and 'bubbles' the event upstream to the 'eldest' parent.

Is this the case or have I got it wrong? Apologies for using slightly useless terminology.

Comment: Your terminology's fine, don't worry. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those times where you need to know what to search for in order to find out what you need to know. In your case, what you're interested in is the ASP.Net page lifecycle.

There is an excellent article on MSDN, at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx, entitled "ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview". It goes into what you're interested in in much more detail than an SO answer could. From the introduction:

> When an ASP.NET page runs, the page goes through a life cycle in which it performs a series of processing steps. These include initialization, instantiating controls, restoring and maintaining state, running event handler code, and rendering. It is important for you to understand the page life cycle so that you can write code at the appropriate life-cycle stage for the effect you intend.
>
> If you develop custom controls, you must be familiar with the page life cycle in order to correctly initialize controls, populate control properties with view-state data, and run control behavior code. The life cycle of a control is based on the page life cycle, and the page raises many of the events that you need to handle in a custom control.